# Computational Expression using Zero

Tags: f#, computation-expression

When using a computational expression, the first definition works but the second does not for Zero.

What is the difference between this:

```
member o.Zero() = 3
```

and this:

```
member o.Zero = fun() -> 3
```

The first evaluates to `unit -> int` and the second to `(unit -> int)`. What is the difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If they are let-bounds, there is no difference. However, in a class definition the first `o.Zero` is a method while the second `o.Zero`is a property.

Computation expression expects a method named `Zero`; that's why it didn't work when you provided a property with the same name.